# Spark custom vocabulary for CountVectorizer and IDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`CountVectorizer` will produce its own list of indices based on entries, e.g.

```
"I Spark"
"Spark need boy"
```

will produce

```
(4, idicies=(1,2), values=(1,1))
(4, indicies=(2,3,4), values=(1,1,1))
```

but I'd like to pass my own vocabulary with, say, ("I":10, "Spark":123,"need":3, "boy":99) so:

```
(4, idicies=(10, 123), values=(1,1))
(4, indicies=(123,3,99), values=(1,1,1))
```

Is this possible? Same for IDF?

Comment: IDF takes data after it was transformed by a CountVectorizer or HashiingTF. As I understand it, it won't have a vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked at this problem. It can be done like this:

`new CountVectorizerModel(uid, vocab).setParent(<Some CountVectorizer>)`

I took this example from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala). You can drop the `uid` and `vocab` is of type `Array[String]` as seen in the definition on CountVectorizerModel:

```
@Since("1.5.0")
class CountVectorizerModel(
    @Since("1.5.0") override val uid: String,
    @Since("1.5.0") val vocabulary: Array[String])
  extends Model[CountVectorizerModel] with CountVectorizerParams with MLWritable {

  import CountVectorizerModel._

  @Since("1.5.0")
  def this(vocabulary: Array[String]) = {
    this(Identifiable.randomUID("cntVecModel"), vocabulary)
    set(vocabSize, vocabulary.length)
  }`
```